# Parsing .Net Date format in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently calling an external API and getting a JSON response.  The data has 2 date fields that I need to parse and display in a table in my app.

The issue I am having is that the dates are in .Net format:

```
/Date(1377183028730-0400)/
```

Any suggestions on how I can parse this into a usable RoR format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a number of milliseconds from an epoch.

You could extract the first part with a regular expression such as

```
if date =~ /Date\((\d+)-(\d+)\)/
  Time.at($1.to_i/1000.0)
end
```

The latter part might be a timezone indicator.

Comment: Use of `date.match(...)` is preferable to the enigmatic Perl-ism `date =~ ...`. The last part is a time-zone indicator (`%z` in `strftime` notation).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ruby's [`strptime` function](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime). Have a look in the [`strftime` function docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for an explanation of the directives that can be used.

Comment: `strptime` doesn't seem happy with `%s` or `%z`.

Comment: strftime formats a Time object.  The problem I have is I need to parse the Date string into a Ruby Time object.

Comment: @tadman `%s` and `%z` both work fine with `strptime` in Ruby on Rails, which is one of the tags for this question. @tagCincy `strftime` formatting directives work fine with `DateTime.strptime` too, but since the string is mainly just the milliseconds from the epoch, `Time.at` works much better than my answer here.